# Why loop starts with i = n/2 for doing heap sort?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heapsort

I need to change max-heap code to min-heap code. I changed some parts, but when I print, I get only the min-heap array by order, not sorted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define MAX_TREE 100

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int key;
}element;

element a[MAX_TREE];

void SWAP(element root, element target, element temp) { 
    root = target;
    target = temp;
}
void adjust(element e[], int root, int n) { //array로 입력된 tree를 min heap으로 adjust(조정해서) sort
    /*adjust the binary tree to etablish the heap*/
    int child, rootkey;
    element temp;
    temp = a[root]; //root element assign
    rootkey = a[root].key; //root element's key value
    child = 2 * root; //root ( a[i] )의 left child
    //leftChild: i * 2 (if i * 2 <= n) rightChild: i * 2 + 1(if 1 * 2 + 1 <= n)
    while (child <= n) { //if child exists
        if ((child < n) &&//compare left child with right child 
            (a[child].key > a[child + 1].key))//
            //if leftChild.key > rightChild.key
            child++;//move to smaller child
        if (rootkey < a[child].key) //if it satisfies min heap
            break; //break when root key is smaller than child's key
        else { //if it doesn't satisfies min heap
            a[child / 2] = a[child];
            //assign child to parent
            child *= 2; 
            //loop until there's no child
        }
    }
    a[child / 2] = temp; //if there's no more child, assign root element to child/2
}
void heapSort(element a[], int n) {
    /*perform a heap sort on a[1:n]*/
    int i;
    element temp;
    temp = a[1];

    for (i = n / 2; i > 0; i--) { //<-This is the part I don't understand
        adjust(a, i, n);
    }
    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i-- ) {
        SWAP(a[1], a[i + 1], temp);
        adjust(a, 1, i);
    }
}
void P1() {
    int n;
    std::fstream in("in1.txt");
    in >> n;
    printf("\n\n%d\n", n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        element temp;
        in >> temp.key;
        a[i] = temp;
    }
    heapSort(a, n);
    //6 5 51 3 19 52 50
}

int main() {
    P1();
}
```

It's my professor's example code. I need to input numbers from file in1.txt.
In that file there are values for `n`, `m1`, `m2`, `m3`...

`n` is the number of key values that will follow. Following `m1`, `m2`, ... are the key values of each element.

After getting input, I store integers in an array that starts with index [1]: it's a binary tree represented as an array.

I need to min-heapify this binary tree and apply heapsort.

This code was originally max-heap sort code. There are maybe some lines I missed to change.

I don't get why I need to start `for` statement with `i = n/2`. What's the reason?

Comment: [What is a debugger, and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173)

Comment: Hint: "Binary" can often mean "split into two things" hence dividing by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `for` statement starts with i=n/2?
>
> This is the part I don't understand

This loop:

```
for (i = n / 2; i > 0; i--) {
    adjust(a, i, n);
}
```

... is the phase where the input array is made into a heap. The algorithm calls `adjust` for every *internal* node of the binary tree, starting with the "last" of those internal nodes, which sits at index `n/2`. This is [Floyd's heap construction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Variations).

There would be no benefit to calling `adjust` on indexes that are greater than `n/2`, as those indices represent *leaves* in the binary tree, and there is nothing to "adjust" there.

The call of `adjust` will move the value at the root of the given subtree to a valid position in that subtree, so that that subtree is a heap. By moving backwards, this accumulates to bigger subtrees becoming heaps, until also the root is a heap.

### The error

The error in your code is the `SWAP` function. As you pass arguments by value, none of the assignments in that function impact `a`.

Correction:

```
void SWAP(element &root, element &target) { 
    element temp = root;
    root = target;
    target = temp;
}
```

And on the caller side, drop `temp`.